# Are there any xsd schemas available for the .runsettings file in Visual Studio 2012 unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, configuration, xsd, visual-studio-2012, mstest

Based on this msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx, in Visual Studio 2012 you need to use an xml file named .runsettings to configure your deployment,code coverage, framework settings etc.

On first glance this looks great as you can hook in adapter settings from any test adapter, e.g. NUnit,MSTest,MBUnit etc. However in my installation of Visual Studio 2012 Premium there are no xsd schemas for creating this file, but there are of course the old schemas for the VS2010 .testsettings file. (xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010" aka %programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas\vstst.xsd)

Has anyone found anything other than the sample on the link above to go for creating the run settings file?

Also have you found how to reference the legacy VS2010 .testsettings file from the .runsettings file as there are no specifics on whether it should be relative or absolute in the "SettingsFile" node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do not have a public xsd for the .runsettings file as yet.

The way to refer your .testsettings file from your .runsettings is shown below. You can use absolute and relative paths to this file.

`<RunSettings>
                        <MSTest>
                            <SettingsFile>my.testsettings</SettingsFile>
                            <ForcedLegacyMode>true</ForcedLegacyMode>
                        </MSTest>
                    </RunSettings>`